# UrBackup: How can i change the storage to a newly created Raid 1?

Tags: debian, backup, raid

Recently

i created a NAS with [OpenMediaVault (OMV 5.6.16-1 usul)](https://www.openmediavault.org/) with an old PC that i have here, my intention with this is to create an external backup for a Windows PC using [UrBackup (2.1.20)](https://www.urbackup.org/), i did the installation using portainer.

I already did a test, and it's working fine but recently i got a hold of two 1Tb HDD and used them to create a new RAID 1 storage, so my question is:

- **How can i set the default storage so that all the backups go to this newly created RAID instead of the default one?**

*Note:* This is a fresh install so i don't have data inside and there is no risk of losing anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should type

```
echo "/media/backup/urbackup" > /etc/urbackup/backupfolder
```

Where  `/media/backup/urbackup` is your backup folder. If the RAID creation create a new directory, just change the backupfolder configuration file.

Note UrBackup seems to be optimised for ZFS or BtrFS.